# pythonのtweepyで自分のツイートにいいねしてきた人をブロックしたい

Tags: python, twitter

teratailとのマルチポストになります。
https://teratail.com/questions/111320

ツイッターで自分のツイートに無差別でいいねしてくるスパムアカウントに嫌気がさして、pythonのtweepyで自動ブロックしてやろうと
思っていたのですが、自分のツイートにいいねしてきた人のツイートIDの取得方法がわからなくて困っています。

tweepyのAPIリファレンスは自動翻訳で翻訳して一通り見たつもりですが、いいねしてきた人のツイートIDを取得するメソッドは
存在しないように思いました。
もしそのようなメソッドがあれば教えていただきたいです。
また、別の取得方法がありましたら教えていただきたいです。
各種キーはすでに設定しておりAPIインスタンスを作成して、自分のツイートとそのIDは取得できております。

最終的にはpythonのtweepyで自分のツイートにいいねしてきた人の中でフォロー数が２１人のアカウントを自動でブロックする
スクリプトにしたいと思っています。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3):

ご自身で調べられた通り、公式APIには「いいね」したユーザの一覧を取得する方法は無いようですが、
自作のPythonコードを書いている方がいましたのでこちらは参考になるでしょうか。

[TwitterAPIに存在しない「いいねしたユーザーを取得」する方法](http://cmpt.hateblo.jp/entry/2017/07/29/171656)

```
import urllib.request
import re

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28982850/twitter-api-getting-list-of-users-who-favorited-a-status

def get_favoritters(post_id):
    try:
        json_data = urllib.request.urlopen('https://twitter.com/i/activity/favorited_popup?id=' + str(post_id)).read()
        json_data=json_data.decode("utf8")
        found_ids = re.findall(r'data-user-id=\\"+\d+', json_data)
        unique_ids = list(set([re.findall(r'\d+', match)[0] for match in found_ids]))
        return unique_ids
    except urllib.request.HTTPError:
        return False
```

なお、コード中のコメントにも記載がありますが上記URLの方は英語版SOでのやり取りを見て
Python3.x向けにコードを書き直したようです。元質問の方はPython2.x向けのコードでした。

[Twitter API - Getting list of users who favorited a status - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28982850/twitter-api-getting-list-of-users-who-favorited-a-status)